# splot with dots doesn't work on Gnuplot 5?

Tags: gnuplot

How to `splot` 3d data under `Gnuplot 5.0` with `dots` style?

For the data file [hosted here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=56419258784295133326) (`SampleData.txt`), using the following code:

```
set datafile separator "|"
splot 'SampleData.txt' u 1:2:3 w dots
```

This is a short clip of the sample data:

```
3|909|1
3|931|1
3|951|1
3|965|1
3|993|1
4|910|1
4|918|1
4|928|1
```

And there are hundreds more lines like that.

[image: Empty plot]

I am getting an empty plot as shown above. Note, that it works on Gnuplot 4.6, as in the [second image posted here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT747.jpg). I can't make it work on version 5.0 though.

Comment: Apparently it helped to switch to 5.0.3 version released week ago, this can be closed.

Comment: If you want to close the question, you can just delete it if you'd like.  Questions are closed for fairly specific reasons, and this doesn't meet one.  Otherwise, you may also self-answer the question and then accept your own answer (after the mandatory waiting period).  That would mark it as answered.  I see that you have reported it on the gnuplot bug page, so you can answer that it was a bug and tell what you did to fix it (upgrade to the latest version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug in Version 5.0 rc2 that is distributed in current Debian's gnuplot5 .deb package. If you happen to use it, it helps to dump the package and install manually from [sources](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/) (upgrading to version 5.0.3 solved the issue for me).